# unset css parameters when animating

Tags: jquery

I started to learn jQuery. I wrote a code, that will cycle the position of an given element by calling functions stored in an array. This works fine for this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#right_column').css({zIndex:1000, position: 'absolute', right: 0, top:200 });
    $('body').css({overflow:'hidden'});
    var funcs = new Array(
                    function(o){
                        $(o).animate({right: 0, top:200}, 1000);
                    },
                    function(o){
                        $(o).animate({top: 0},1000);
                    },
                    function(o){
                        $(o).animate({right: 300},1000);
                    },
                    function(o){
                        $(o).animate({right: 300, top:200},1000);
                    }
                );
    var flip=0;
    $('#right_column').click(function self(){
            funcs[++flip % funcs.length]('#right_column');
    });
 });
</script>
```

but if I change the positions parameter like this

```
    var funcs = new Array(
                    function(o){
                        $(o).animate({right: 0, top:200}, 1000);
                    },
                    function(o){
                        $(o).animate({top: 0},1000);
                    },
                    function(o){
                        $(o).animate({left: 0},1000);
                    },
                    function(o){
                        $(o).animate({right: 300, bottom:0},1000);
                    }
                );
```

it breaks.

I assume, that the complementary parameters (top<->bottom; left<->right) interfere, as they would do in plain css as well.

So my question is: **How can I reset css parameters to undefined?**

**edit**

`animate` doesn't seem to be able to handle `auto` probably. It didn't change the behavior.
with `css()` it works.

```
    var funcs = new Array(
                    function(o){
                        $(o).css({right:0, bottom:0,left:'auto', top:'auto'})
                        console.log('funcs 0');
                    },
                    function(o){
                        $(o).css({top:0, right:0, left:'auto', bottom:'auto'})
                        console.log('funcs 1');
                    },
                    function(o){
                        $(o).css({left:0, top:0, right:'auto', bottom:'auto'})
                        console.log('funcs 2');
                    },
                    function(o){
                        $(o).css({right:'auto', top:'auto',left:0, bottom:0})
                        console.log('funcs 3');
                    }   
                );
```

running `css({...:'auto'})` before/after `animate()` destroyed (of cause) the animation

**any other hint?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to reset those values change them to 'auto'

```
top: auto;
left: auto;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
```

Edit:

You could add "targets".

```
 <div id="top" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0"></div>
 <div id="bottom" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:auto;bottom:0px"></div>
```

Now you can use the values of your targets for your animation:

```
$("#bottom").offset().top
$("#bottom").offset().left
```

Animation:

```
 $(o).animate({ top : $("#bottom").offset().top, left : $("#bottom").offset().left });
```